# How to run a standalone application from the current one?

Tags: python, process

I've got an GUI application written in python.
After GUI starts it should run standalone daemon. But if I close GUI or it crashes, daemon quits too. Is there a way to run one application from another independently?

Comment: Since the answer well vary between Windows vs unix-like, which OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't start a daemon, I have a pygtk program which starts another program using [subprocess.Popen()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) with shell=True.  For example:

```
import subprocess

def callback(self, widget, date=None):
    cmd = "Your command here"
    other_process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Since this is a callback attached to a button, pygtk takes care of things when the button is clicked.  Even when I shutdown the initial pygtk gui program, the second program keeps running.  FWIW, this is on a CentOS Linux system.

I did something similar with TkInter once, but don't have that code available to me right now.  That was on a Windows XP system.  My recollection is that the second process continued running after the first was stopped.

Comment: But if your GUI quits, `cmd` will shutdown as well which is exactly the problem that the questioner is facing.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim:  I just re-tested and stopping the parent gui process didn't stop the child process using code nearly identical to the above.

Comment: Windows or Linux? I think on Windows, the child process gets somehow "disconnected" from the parent but on UNIX, it's the other way round till you "daemonise" it.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim:  As the edit to my answer says, the testing I referred to in my earlier response to you was on Linux.  (I don't even have access to a Windows box right now.)

Answer (score 2):

Under Linux, I've handled this by having my parent process (in your case the GUI), launch the second python process via subprocess or os.system.  The 2nd process immediately daemonizes itself.  To do that see [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) or [here](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).